# Appendix suddenly right aligned?

Tags: appendices, ragged2e

I am writing a thesis using a template I didn't create myself, which worked great so far. But when I put some text in the appendix, it suddenly is right aligned, with a ragged left side. I have found nothing in the preamble that looks even remotely relevant for this. Anyone knows what the cause of the problem might be?

This is roughly what happens before:

```
\mainmatter
\input{content/1-Intro}
\bibliography{bib/BibtexDatabase}
\appendix
\input{content/Za-Anhang}
```

The content files simply start with `\chapter{Bla}`

Comment: Suddenly? LaTeX is not Quantum Physics ;-) You should show us what you have!

Comment: Ok, you are right, "suddenly" = "I just tried it for the first time and have no idea why it is happening". Ironically, my thesis is about quantum physics ;D

Comment: Usually this happens when a command is forgotten to be scoped and leaks to all chapters that comes after it. Try to find at least where it starts by moving the `\end{document}` all the way up and slowly pushing it to the end until you get an idea which macro etc.

Comment: Oh wow, this was actually a great tip! I use a `\flushright` command to sign the declaration of own work, and apparently it is still turned on afterwards. How do I turn it off again? putting `{}` around it also leaves it without effect on the line that I want to force to the right.

Comment: Group with an extra pair of braces `{\flushright contents\par}` or instead of `\flushright` use the environment `\begin{raggedleft} contents \end{raggedleft}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comment by percusse (no idea how to link users, is it possible at all?) put me in the right direction. The problem was the `\flushright` command that I used on the very last line of the document to force the place and date to the right

```
\flushright Ulm, \today
```

Replacing it with `\hfill` solved the problem

```
\hfill Ulm, \today
```

For the record: Putting `{}` around the line made the appendix left aligned again, but had no effect on the line itself. Same for putting it in the `raggedleft` environment.

Comment: `flushright` is an environment, while `\raggedleft` is a declaration.